# Correcting broken titles with spaces between letters in PHP

Tags: php, regex, text, data-cleaning

I have a bunch of broken titles where each letter is always separated by one space or more. The words in these titles are separated by more than the amount of spaces than each letter, but the amount of spaces varies.

Here are some examples of titles (the minus sign denotes a space).

```
"H-E-L-L-O--W-O-R-L-D"

"H--E--L--L--O----W--O--R--L--D"

"H--E--L-L--O---W--O--R--L--D----A-N-D----G-O-O--D-B--Y-E"

"Y--O--U----A--R--E----W-O-N--D-E-R-F-U--L"
```

I want to correct these titles but all my solutions so far have been overly complicated. It feels like it should be a simple issue.

Any solutions?

---

EDIT: This is the solution I picked in the end, which is based on the average,

```
function filterSpacesBetweenLetters($str)
{
    if (preg_match_all('/ +/', $str, $matches)) {
        $lengthValues = array_map('strlen', $matches[0]);

        $countValues = array_count_values($lengthValues);

        $average = array_sum(array_keys($countValues)) / count($countValues);

        $minLength = ceil($average);

        $words = preg_split('/ {' . $minLength . ',}/', $str);

        $words = array_map(function ($str) {
            return str_replace(' ', '', $str);
        }, $words);

        return implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: I feel this is not possible, there is too much inconstancy with the number of dashes in a single example of text to discern what isn't a space and what is a space character. Why do your titles look like this? I was going to suggest find the `-{2,}` groups and use the largest one as the space character, but its all over the place.

Comment: The words in the titles are always separated by more than the amount of spaces between each letter so there is a consistency.

Comment: Third line has both four and three dashes as word separators.

Comment: Yes but it never has two dashes as a word separator.

Comment: Your first line has two dashes as a word separator.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the third line specifically. Yes the first line has two dashes as a word separator, but there it only has one dash to separate letters.

Comment: You could get the number of variations of # of spaces in the string, average them, and anything above the average is a word break, and below is not. For example your last string has 1, 2, 4 spaces, average is 2.333, so only 4 spaces would be a word break. But how do you handle that if you have 1,2,3 spaces where the average is 2?

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: I don't see how you can decide that `H-E-L--L---O----W-O--R--L-D` is supposed to be `HELL O WORLD` or `HELLO WORLD`

Comment: I will probably have to use a dictionary as an extra step for cases like that. I made a function that just uses the average and of course it gives HELL O WORLD, but it does not get much better than this I guess.

Comment: Are you sure that those spaces are actually spaces and you're not just looking at raw/improperly-handled UTF-16? Where are you sourcing the data from originally? Run it through `bin2hex()` and show us what that looks like.

Comment: Yes they are spaces. The data is just broken.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. By the way It can't deal with `h e l l o` as a spaced out single word.

Answer (score 2):

All I can think of is to have a mechanism that looks for the largest count of dash characters in sequence and apply the replacement rules in either 3/4 or 1/2 sets

```
$text = <<<END
H-E-L-L-O--W-O-R-L-D
H--E--L--L--O----W--O--R--L--D
H--E--L-L--O---W--O--R--L--D----A-N-D----G-O-O--D-B--Y-E
Y--O--U----A--R--E----W-O-N--D-E-R-F-U--L
END;

$lines = explode( PHP_EOL, $text );

foreach( $lines as $key => $line )
{
  if( preg_match_all( '/-*/', $line, $matches ) !== false )
  {
    $counts = array_map( 'strlen', $matches[0] );
    if( max( $counts ) >= 3 )
    {
      $line = preg_replace('/-{3,4}/',' ', $line );
      $line = preg_replace('/-{1,2}/','', $line );
    }
    else
    {
      $line = replace( '--', ' ', $line );
      $line = replace( '-', '', $line );
    }
  }
  echo $line . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Anything outside of these rules will fail to match, double spaces will mess it up totally.

Prints

```
HELLO WORLD
HELLO WORLD
HELLO WORLD AND GOODBYE
YOU ARE WONDERFUL
```

Comment: This is limited because it works only for fixed lengths of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an approach with no looping (but does use some preg which I was also trying to avoid).

Find the longest contiguous number of spaces. Tokenize the string, splitting on that 'largest space', to get an array of 'words'. Remove the white space from each word. Put it back together.

```
<?php

function stripSpace($str) {
    return str_replace(' ', '', $str);
}

$test = 'H E L L O  W O R L D';
//$test = 'H  E  L  L  O    W  O  R  L  D    A  G  A  I  N';

preg_match_all('#(\s)\1+#', $test, $m);
usort($m[0], function($a, $b) {
    return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? 1 : -1;
});
$m = strlen($m[0][0]);

$parts = explode(str_repeat(chr(32), $m), $test);

$parts = array_map('stripSpace', $parts);

echo implode($parts, chr(32));
```